# Can't open multiple files in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Whether I'm in a Single or 2 Column mode, I am only able to have 2-3 open files (tabs) per window.

When I hit what appears to be a limit, attempts to open a file (by clicking in Sidebar View) will replace an already open file.

Is there a setting I can change or have I hit a working-as-designed limitation?

Environment:

- Sublime Text 3 Stable Build 3103
- OS X (El Capitan) 10.11.4

BTW: If I use File Open it does not appear to have the same problem as I can open may files that way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you open a file from the sidebar with a *single click*, its tab will only remain open, if you edit or save the file. If you want the tab to stay open, *double-click* on a file in the sidebar.

You can override this default behaviour in your settings:

```
{
    "preview_on_click": false
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this, but it doesn't do what I was hoping... I want a single click to open a persistent file so I don't have to double-click every time. Is there a way to accomplish this?