# Sublime Text 3 can't open some files one by one

Tags: sublimetext3

When I open a file in Sublime, I must do any changes in it to open one more (I use whitespace usually). If I don't do it, the new file will be opened instead of the previous (previous will be closed). It's really annoying especially when I need to open 5-10 files right away.
How to fix? I couldn't find any settings for it.

Comment: Single clicks of files in the sidebar preview the file; the tab uses *italic* text to show you that the view is a `transient preview`; editing the file converts it to a full view. You can commit to opening a file by double clicking it instead. As @flaxel mentions in their answer, you can turn off `preview_on_click` as well. That still requires that you double click to open files, but you will not get the previews on single clicks (which should remind you that you need to double click instead)

Comment: Thank you so much, it allows me to keep both functions =)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it works, but you can override this behavior with this setting:

```
{
    "preview_on_click": false
}
```

Also see "[Can't open multiple files in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242120/cant-open-multiple-files-in-sublime-text-3)".